# Cookie not being saved after an ajax call in Spotify (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spotify

I'm working on a Spotify app and I'm also trying to log into Reddit with JQuery's $.ajax function. The login works and I can see the response cookie in the dev tools but when I try and access any part of Reddit's API that requires that the login cookie be sent with the call it fails and it looks like the cookie is never being sent. Also, looking at the 'Cookies' part of the dev tools shows that the site (app) has no cookies.

Here's the login call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/login',
    data: {
        'user': $user,
        'passwd': $password
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("logged in!");
    }
});
```

And here's the vote call (userhash copied from the cookie I could see in dev tools):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/vote',
    data: {
        'id': $id,
        'dir': 1,
        'uh': $userhash
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **xhrFields** property added in jQuery 1.5.1 may help:

Login call:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/login',
data: {
    'user': $user,
    'passwd': $password
},
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
success: function() {
    alert("logged in!");
}
});
```

Vote call:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/vote',
data: {
    'id': $id,
    'dir': 1,
    'uh': $userhash
},
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

That will tell it to set the withCredentials property of the XMLHTTPRequest object to true, which is needed for cookies to be passed when using cross-domain AJAX calls.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to change the behavior at all. Do I need to change anything else about the call is made?